# Java Mail API slow down the application performance. Is there way to improve it?

Tags: java, multithreading, email

I am trying to send a welcome mail to user who signup into my application using social login i.e google, facebook. Firstly i am saving the user and then i am calling send method from a class like : 
emailServiceImpl.sendSimpleMessage();
I am using event handler ApplicationListener for saving and sending welcome mail. The problem with it is the view is rendered after saving and sending the mail so, for sending mail it is taking so much time(3 seconds approx.). Is there any other way to do it. Please help me?

Comment: Show us the code, please... How have you handled multithreading?

Comment: The sending part should be done by another thread. Dont let the view wait for it

Comment: You could always move it away from the processing thread, have it added to a queue and have a service worker that runs every x seconds or minutes to process it

Comment: You should use separate `java.util.Thread` for long-running operations like sending email

Comment: @Quyet thanks for your solution but can you explain how to do with sample example please. I haven't worked on multi-threading with spring